# Is there an event that is triggered when a child window is opened?

Tags: javascript, popup

I want to close child windows that opened by another script.

and also is there anyway to get the list of already opened child windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far knowing when a window is opened, you can redefine `window.open` to know when windows are being opened.

```
open = (function(open) {
    return function() {
         console.log('tried to open window');
         if(isOkayToOpenWindow) {
             return open.apply(this, arguments);
         }
    };
})(open);
```

Here, put an expression in place of `isOkayToOpenWindow` that decides if you actually want to open the window. If you want to block opening windows *all* the time, it's even simpler: `open = function() {};`

The will only work for calls to `window.open`, not for `<a target="_blank"></a>`

There is no way to get references to windows already opened.

Comment: Sorry...incomplete sentence fixed.

Comment: you need to explain `isOkay`

Comment: If you store the handles or the names, you can close the window using `if (windowHandle && !windowHandle.closed) windowHandle.close();` or `window.open('','windowname').close()`